# Having trouble making each dot a different color, can't figure out how to make each point different color stored in the arraylist

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Having trouble making each dot a different random color and staying the same color and not changing every dot the same color having to use dr.java. it would repeatedly change the old and new dots into the same color, and would keep one dot as a old color as the new dot was made

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class DotsPanel extends JPanel
{
private final int SIZE = 6;  

private ArrayList<Point> pointList;


public DotsPanel()
{
  pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();

  addMouseMotionListener (new DotsListener());
  addMouseListener (new DotsListener());
  setBackground(Color.black);
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
}
```

can't get it to paint just one when i put a new dot it changes the old ones to the new color also

```java
public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
{ 


  super.paintComponent(page);

  Random rand= new Random();
 int r=rand.nextInt(255);
 int g=rand.nextInt(255);
 int b=rand.nextInt(255);
  page.setColor(new Color(r,g,b));


  for (Point spot : pointList)
  {

     page.fillOval(spot.x-SIZE, spot.y-SIZE, SIZE*2, SIZE*2);


  }
 }


  private class DotsListener implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener
  {

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
  {
     pointList.add(event.getPoint());

     repaint();
////////
///////    was unable to put the page color down here it would not recognize it.
  }
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
  {
     pointList.add(event.getPoint());

     repaint();
  }


  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {}
  }
  }
```

Comment: The easiest way to solve this is to create a custom class (e.g. `ColoredDot`) which encapsulates both a `Point` and a `Color`. Store those in the `ArrayList ` and when iterating the list to draw the points, access the color of that `ColoredDot` and change the color of the `Graphics` object. BTW - do you have a question?

Comment: General tip: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Don't generated random colors in a painting method. You can't control when the painting methods are called so you don't want the color to change randomly. See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working code that shows how to paint Rectangles of different colors.